# "GDALWarpOptions.Validate(): hSrcDS is not set" when reading a VRT pointing to a STACTA

Tags: gdal, rasterio, vrt, stac

Using `rasterio.open()` I was trying to read a VRT. This VRT pointed to another VRT and this in turn pointed to a STACTA file.

This error message appeared:

`rasterio.errors.RasterioIOError: Read or write failed. GDALWarpOptions.Validate(): hSrcDS is not set.`

- GDAL: 2.4
- `rasterio`: 1.2.10 (built from source distribution for GDAL 2.4)

Answer (score 0):

[GDAL's STACTA driver](https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/stacta.html#stacta-spatio-temporal-asset-catalog-tiled-assets) was added in GDAL version 3.3. Even if using the `rasterio` 1.2.10 wheel it would only include GDAL 3.2.1, according to the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/e7dec89045a82b9e606847363000d237cb7c399a/CHANGES.txt#L258).

The [release notes for `rasterio 1.3b1`](https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/releases/tag/1.3b1) state:

> the binary wheels on PyPI include GDAL 3.5.0rc4

Using `rasterio 1.3b1` the error message disappears and the STACTA can be read.